# RecyclerView with swipe action menu

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView with the implementation of ItemTouchHelper. I am dragging and sorting the items in RecyclerView using ItemTouchHelper.

Also I am performing different actions on different direction of swipe. If user goes from left to right (Swipe) I just Deactivate status of item. If he perform right to left swipe I activate the relevant item.

What I want: 
But now here comes the change, What I want is that I need to show some icons after I perform right or left swipe. And By clicking on those icons/buttons I want to perform action then.

Problem: 
Problem is as I told you I have implementation of ItemTouchHelper, then how I am doing to perform what I wanted (as described above)

How to solve this? I have seen many libraries but they have limitations, also as the app has very much things going and there are some more implementations on RecyclerView used in our app, so I really do not want to risk the rest of implementations for the sake of this..

**UPDATE 1:** 
To clear my question more I am going to add on more. Right now My implementation is something like [this](https://medium.com/@zackcosborn/step-by-step-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-and-undo-7bbae1fce27e). But this is not what I want. I want to show swipe menu for any type of swipe I mean either it is left or right I want to show some icons on left and right side of item

You can take iOS swipe menu as an example (see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20Swipe%20menu%20UITableview&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK819PK819&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSzMLV3t7iAhVJyaQKHYZ6A7AQ_AUIECgB&biw=1888&bih=867#imgrc=ThuGzuOWolyIHM:)). I want exactly same behavior in android.

Comment: If I understand you correctly I'd suggest you to use https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout

Comment: @AlexeiArtsimovich this library has one direction at a time

Comment: it's not that hard to add swipe without libraries

Comment: @ManojPerumarath please show me some example

Comment: https://medium.com/@zackcosborn/step-by-step-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-and-undo-7bbae1fce27e

Comment: @ManojPerumarath in your example there is no swie menu, I am doing same as you shared in link, but what I want is something different. check updated question

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Adding swipe is not hard, as the OP stated, but adding swipe with stops and animations is a different story, because ItemTouchHelper and its derivatives (and most libraries) deal with a Canvas directly.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes you are right. ItemTouchHelper is not what I want. And it does not give us option to alter its behavior

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the impossible: suggest a library that doesn't exist (as you have already found out).

You're asking people to also find a solution for a problem you only briefly describe. You're not providing any code whatsoever, nor any specific issue you're facing when trying to come up with a solution; you're essentially expecting magic to happen.

#### How can you make this better?

Provide something like: "I'm attempting to implement a swipe solution for a recycler view's row; when I try to do  YYYY is happening instead. Hhere's my piece of code where I do , calculated like this , am I missing something?"

Anyway...

You claim to be using an ItemTouchHelper already, so, if you look at [how a very basic one works](https://github.com/Gryzor/SwipeNoLib/blob/master/swipenolib/src/main/java/com/gryzor/swipenolib/RecyclerViewItemSwipeHelper.java), you'll notice that the helper will ultimately draw on the canvas directly via:

```
   @Override
   public void onChildDraw(
            final Canvas canvas,
            final RecyclerView recyclerView,
            final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            final float deltaX,
            final float deltaY,
            final int actionState,
            final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
```

This is derived from the platform `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`. So...

If you want to implement your solutions, you'll need to implement it there to do things like stop dragging, draw the content (icons), etc.

It's not a trivial solution and getting the whole thing right is difficult; more so if you introduce "*some more implementations on RecyclerView*".

I hope this answer points you in the right direction, and that your next related question is more about what you've tried (and failed) to do, than a "please do this for me" scenario. (If your intentions weren't those, please apologize, but you spent 5 minutes typing this question and it would take hours/days to implement this, so set your expectations this time).

Finally, when I wrote [this](https://github.com/Gryzor/SwipeNoLib), I realized most people wanted iOS swipe behavior; unfortunately, said behavior is not pre-implemented (like on iOS) on Android and you have to deal with it yourself; it's not impossible nor the *most difficult* task on earth to do on Android, but will give you a few headaches if you're *hacking RecyclerView* too much.

#### UPDATE

You've realized now, that ItemTouchHelper has a problem. It draws on the Canvas directly, so it has no knowledge of a Layout, View, Margin, etc. These are all things that live outside the realm of the touch helper. The helper is given a canvas, and drawing capabilities and that's it.

Where does this canvas size come from? 
Well, it's calculated during the layout/measure pass(es) for the RecyclerView and its views.

How do I then stop dragging "at exactly the center of the screen" then?

Pass the values to your Helper; remember that the responsibility of calculating where the middle of the screen is, is not in the TouchHelper's contract; but your Activity/Fragment does know this. Provide the information the Touch Helper needs to perform the things you want it to perform.

Revert "back" to the original position, means knowledge of what the initial state was, etc. All this information is known by the RecyclerView and beyond, not the TouchHelper.

So you'd need to measure your layouts, save some values, pass them to the touchhelper so it can operate, etc.

As you can see, the full picture starts to become more and more complicated. My advice to you is:

1. Try to push this feature OUT as "the platform doesn't do it it will take time, it's not worth" (the worthiness and discoverability of swipe actions is dubious at best, but it's an ubiquitous action nowadays so you may have to do it regardless).
2. If you really have to do this, abstract things as much as you can, create all the classes/interfaces you think you can need, even if you end up with a "`MiddleScreenCalculatorDelegate`" kind of thing. It will be easier to fix later, but at least have each component do a very small subset of things.

Lastly, your item touch helper will have to calculate how much offset (delta) has the view been swiped already and stop when it reaches a known threshold.

Good luck :)

p.s.: I suggest you post a different question with specific issue(s) to get better help, this answer is very unhelpful as it is. :)

Comment: you are right bro. you have given hint to use onChildDraw to accomplish what I wanted. Whereas I was thinking to hide the icons beneath the Layout and to move the main layout left/right by using onTouchListener over the layout that I want to move. In this way I can show icons on left and right side. , How about this??

Comment: if I use OnChildDraw, How I am going to stop the movement at exact half of screen also How I am going to revert it back in original position. the iOS example you given is exactly same behavior I want

Comment: See updated answer; unfortunately, that's as far as I can go. :) Good luck!

Comment: ok, I am thinking to go with TouchListener. what do you think of it?